# SQL Developer DEFINE date

Tags: date, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to change the &_DATE variable in SQL Developer?

Whenever I run the following code, it just shows todays date:
DEFINE RUN_DATE = &_DATE

I'd like to find a way to format the query so it finds the last day in the month.

Also, if possible, to change the format to show as YYMMDD?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select '&_DATE' from dual;
old   1: select '&_DATE' from dual
new   1: select '23-JUN-20' from dual

'23-JUN-2
---------
23-JUN-20

SQL> alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYYMMDD';

Session altered.

SQL> select '&_DATE' from dual;
old   1: select '&_DATE' from dual
new   1: select '20200623' from dual

'2020062
--------
20200623

SQL>
```

_DATE is defined to store result of the SYSDATE function in the database. It's output is based on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting for your session.

Or in SQL Developer -

[image]

But, you want the last day of the month...we'll, we have the LAST_DAY() function for you!

```
select LAST_DAY('&_DATE')
  from DUAL;
```

Returns '20200630' because we submitted _DATE which returns June 23 2020, so the function returns the last day of June 2020.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply (with screenshots too!). The NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting makes much more sense now. Much appreciated.

If I could please ask a follow-up on the dates... How would I go about putting the last day into a DEFINE variable?

It works with me hard-coding the date here:
DEFINE RUN_DATE = '20200531';
SELECT * FROM SALES_&RUN_DATE;

The following code doesn't work but is it possible to have the date dynamically change to be something like this:
DEFINE RUN_DATE = LAST_DAY('&_DATE');
SELECT * FROM SALES_&RUN_DATE;